useContext within a hook, or hook within useContext [React]
I need to share some state across components, so I decided to use a custom Context. Within that context, I'm calling a custom hook called useChat() that returns some state variables.  However, is this the best practice?  Or should I call useContext within useChat?
My state was originally all in the context, but I decided to pull it out into a hook useChat instead since it was getting quite long and unreadable. However, I'm not sure if this is a good pattern.
Throughout my components, I'm calling useContext(ChatContext).  Should I consume the context within useChat instead and call useChat throughout my components?
Here is my current code. My ChatProvider is calling my custom useChat() hook.
type ChatContextType = { ... }

export const ChatContext = createContext<ChatContextType> ({ ... });

export const ChatProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    { chatId, message, chatTitle, ... } = useChat() // custom hook. is this best practice?
}

Here is my useChat() hook:
import { useState } from "react";
import { Chat, ChatMessage } from "@/components/ChatInput/classes";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const useChat = () => {
    const [chatId, setChatId] = useState(nanoid());
    const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");
    const [chatTitle, setChatTitle] = useState<string>("");
    const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState<ChatMessage[]>([]); // all chats
    const router = useRouter();

    const startNewChat = () => {
        setChatId((prevId) => {
            const newId = nanoid(); // Generate a new unique ID
            return newId;
        });
        setChatTitle((prevTitle) => {
            const title = '';
            return title;
        })
        setChatMessages((prevMessages) => {
            const messages = [] as ChatMessage[];
            return messages;
        })

    };

    return {
        chatId,
        setChatId,
        message,
        setMessage,
        chatTitle,
        setChatTitle,
        chatMessages,
        setChatMessages,
        startNewChat,
    }

};
export default useChat;

Should I instead create and manage the context within my useChat hook?

So basically you are asking difference bw useContext(ChatContext) vs useChat(), where const useChat = () => useContext(ChatContext) ?

@TusharShahi I updated my code with my useChat() hook. it returns several state variables.  I'm asking if it's it's an acceptable pattern to call useChat within my ChatProvider.  Or should I do the opposite, where within my useChat function, I create the context there?

A better option would be to store the state variables using the useState() hook. Here is the structure of how your code should look.
import { useState } from "react";

export const ChatContext = createContext<ChatContextType> ({ ... });

export const ChatProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
    const [var, setVar] = useState();
    
    <ChatContext.Provider value={{ var, setVar }}>
        { children }
    </ChatContext.Provider>
}

Also, you can use a custom hook for calling the useContext() hook. It is, totally, up to you.

I don't think it's OK to call useState from within ChatProvider, is it? (Doesn't that violate the Rules of Hooks?)

@ruakh No this is a valid pattern. I use it all the time. ChatProvider is really just a normal component that happens to wrap its children with a context provider

@BrianThompson: Oh, yes, I see. Good call. :-)

The variables were originally within my ChatProvider, but I pulled them out into useChat() to help with readability. I updated my question with my useChat() hook implementation to clarify. it returns several state variables there.
